# iOS Same .h and .m for few TableViewController

Tags: ios, tableview

i want to use the same .h and .m for few tableviewcontroller. BUT, i want to do different things according to the current view. The problem is, i don't know how to differentiate my TableViewController (i see there is storyboard id, how to use it ?), how to say If it's the viewNumeroOne i do it, else if the viewNumerotwo i do it.

Or, maybe i need to have a .h and .m for each TableViewController ? But it seems not be the best solution.

Someone to help me ?

Thx,

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your exact use-case, but you might want to use `prepareForSegue` from the previous ViewController to pass a  flag to your TableViewController.

You'll need to add an identifier to your segue, in the example below I use `MoveToTableViewController`.

For example:

```
  - (void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"MoveToTableViewController"]) {
          MyTableViewController *tableViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
           [tableViewController setTableViewControllerMode:TableViewControllerModeTime];
    }
}
```

In this case, the `TableViewControllerModeTime` should be part of an `enum`, which you'll need to declare in MyTableViewController.h (above the `@interface` tag)

```
typedef enum TableViewControllerMode {
    TableViewControllerModeTime,
    TableViewControllerModeDate,
    TableViewControllerModeUserData
} TableViewControllerMode ;
```

You should also add

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) TableViewControllerMode tableViewControllerMode;
```

To your `MyTableViewController.h` file, but this @property should be between the `@interface` and `@end` tags of `MyTableViewController`

Comment: To be precise i have a form divided in few tableviewController. I'm sorry, but i'm a little noob in Objective C, and i didn't understand your solution :/

Comment: The first problem is, i'm directly on a tableviewcontroller, and after, i don't see how can i know on which tableviewcontroller i am :/

Answer (score 0):

To do this, I create small hidden UIViews with a clear background in each ViewController and link them to the .h file as IBOutlets with proper names like 'checkViewControllerOne' 'checkViewControllerTwo' and so on.

Then in the code you can ask for the ViewController like this:

```
if (checkViewControllerOne) {
    //do stuff for controller one
}
if (checkViewControllerTwo) {
    //do stuff for controller two
}
```

I'm sure there are more elegant ways to do this but this approach works fine and is probably the fastest and easiest one.

Comment: mhhh, it's not stupid :D i wait to see an other solution, but thx :)

Answer (score 0):

You can have an abstract superclass with all the code that you desire the viewControllers to share, and then concrete subclasses for each individual use which only override what is necessary for each different use...

Comment: Yes, so like i said, i will have a .h and .m for each tableviewcontroller. It's a solution, but i want to see how is it possible to do it on the same file^^

Comment: You can make separate implementation and interface for these subclasses directly underneath the abstract superclass, ie in the same .h and .m files...